# dropdown menu, Brootstrap, menu center, text left-sided

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I am sure somebody has aleady posted such a question but I could not find a solution.

I am using Ruby on Rails, Brootstrap and I want to be my dropdown menu(whole) in the middle of the page, but the text (links like We, What we do and etc...) in the dropdown-menu should be left-sided.

How can I do it?

```
 <div class="btn-toolbar">
      <div class="btn-group">


    <button id="action-btn" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      About us
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="del">
           <strong> We</strong>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>

        <div class="mcol">
          <ul class ="sub">
            <div class ="subcolumns menuactivity">
              <a href="details"> What we do </a>
            </li>

      <a href="edit"> Countries </a>
    </div>
  </ul>
  <li>
    <a href="del">
      <strong>References </strong>
    </a>
  </li>
  </ul>


  <div class="btn-group">
    <button id="action-btn" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      News & Events
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="del">
          <strong>Calender</strong>
        </a>
      </li>
      <ul class ="sub">
        <div class ="subcolumns menuactivity">
          <li>
            <a href="details"> News archive</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap as it is by default you can try below

```
  <a class="pull-left" href="details"> What we do </a>
```

I have updated with an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/acc8t/

I did this by using below css

```
.sub{margin-left:0px;}
```

Comment: I have a menu consisting of 6 buttons and they all have a dropwodn menu consisting of 5-7 links. Isnt there a general solution not that I should add to all my options your idea?

Comment: I have updated the solution with what I think you're asking for. Try it out

Answer (score 0):

I have founf as well another solution already.
Just to put in css the following code:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  text-align: left;
   }

.btn-toolbar{
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom:40px;
}​
```